# android: ¿Al deslizar el scroll view dentro de un fragment recarga todo el fragment?

Tags: android

Buen día.

Tengo un fragment en el cual dentro de el tengo un scrollView , tengo una serie de datos cargados, pero cada vez que lo deslizo (hacia abajo o hacia arriba) recarga todo el fragment.¿como podría solucionar esta situación?.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Hola, agrega tu codigo

Comment: @devjav si no has solucionado esto, considera agregar tu código.